# What is the best/safest way to bring a case of wine from Italy to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, alcohol

I will be traveling with my wife to Italy, and we would like to bring a case or two of wine back home to Texas. I've checked the rules of the local governing body (TABC), and they allow each person to bring in [up to 3 gallons of wine](https://www.tabc.texas.gov/poe/how_much_can_i_bring_back.asp). Our concern is with the logistics of this. Obviously, it cannot be a carry-on, but if we put it in checked luggage, we are concerned with breaking. What is the most effective way to get wine from Italy to Texas?

Comment: You need to look at USCBP restrictions, not just Texas

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that. There doesn't appear to be a limit on amount imposed by US CBP, as long as it doesn't appear to be for commercial use. The original question, about logistics, still stands.

Comment: Logistically, the best way would be to have it shipped, unless you travel very light, as it would add about 5 kilos per gallon... 30 pounds for the 3 gallons; overweight..

Comment: Even if I answered, I still have some problems getting what you are asking. Your concern is the logistic and what is the most effective way to get wine from Italy to Texas, but you have already decided to transport it as checked luggage. What sort of answers do you really expect other than "pack it well"?

Comment: Have you looked at [wine shipper boxes](https://www.dalluva.com/wine-journal/bringing-wine-home-from-italy/) already? You'll want to go all out on a heavy-duty one, not flimsy cardboard, but if you talk to enough folks in the wine and tourism industries in Italy, you'll be far from the first person with these questions and someone will point you to a supplier.

Comment: @motoDrizzt , I have edited my question to remove the sense of certainty about transporting it as checked luggage. Any helpful input about getting cases of wine from Italy to Texas would be appreciated, including "your assumptions are wrong; change them".

Comment: @GTonyJacobs well, I have to excuse myself and I changed my answer, in the meantime, 'cause I totally missed the part about the TABC (and I read the question three times, before answering :-\ )

Comment: For clarity, do you mean a standard 12 bottle case?

Comment: I recently looked into US CBP policy (for a similar amount of wine - we ended up being sixteen bottles).   Basically, as long as it's for personal use you're fine.  I suspect that bringing back a mismatched case (as you're likely to) will be less suspicious than bringing back a matched case. Your big obstacle is likely to be your airline's baggage allowance, so check that ahead of time!

Comment: @Johns-305 , everything I "mean" here is flexible. I mean whatever works. We'd like to return with a quantity of wine. Twelve 750mL bottles is under 3 gallons, so that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @motoDrizzt , I would have accepted your answer, but you deleted it :/

Comment: 'cause I felt it wasn't a real answer. I mean...you asked how to send the wine, so the answer should focus on that, and then I could use a comment to say "anyway, I think it's a bad idea 'cause blah blah blah".

Instead my answer was "don't do it", and that's not what this site is for :-)

 Additionally, if by experience you have found an answer yourself that you feel is not the same as the already posted ones, you should post it and mark it as accepted :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Fodor's Travel](http://www.fodors.com/news/how-to-pack-wine-in-your-luggage-11219) offered sound advice in its article published March 3, 2015, on **How to Pack Wine in Your Luggage**:

> For oenophiles who love to travel, a bottle of wine can serve as the perfect vacation souvenir or gift. But as your luggage is handled by various people and jostled on planes and conveyor belts, the risk of having that expensive bottle of red break and spill all over your clothes increases. These handy tips will help you bring home your favorite pours and avoid any airport mishaps.
>
> **BE AWARE OF AIRPORT RESTRICTIONS**
>   You never want to be surprised at airport security, so it’s important to understand the ins and outs of TSA rules for transporting alcohol before purchasing a bottle. The best way to transport wine is through checked baggage. The only restrictions in this category relate to alcohol content. Travelers can’t transport bottles with more than 70 percent alcohol content and can only take five liters of alcohol between 24 and 70 percent. Fortunately, wine almost always falls below 24 percent alcohol content, meaning there is no limit to the amount of alcohol allowed in checked bags. Carry-on liquid restrictions do apply to alcohol, meaning you can’t bring liquids in containers larger than 3.4 ounces in a carry-on. The only way to get around this rule is by purchasing alcohol after you’ve gotten through security at one of the duty-free stores. Duty-free allowances differ depending on country; the U.S. typically allows one duty-free liter of alcohol per person.
>
> **PACK BAGS SECURELY**
>   There are a couple of different strategies to use when packing wine in a checked bag. One method involves putting the wine bottle in a sock, wrapping a piece of clothing around the bottle’s neck until it’s as wide as the bottom of the bottle, and then wrapping the bottle with additional clothing pieces (like shirts). You can add a watertight plastic bag for some extra security. Travelers can also use bubble wrap, instead of clothing, to wrap the bottle, which adds some additional protection for the journey. Regardless of how you wrap the bottle, make sure to pack it in the middle of a full suitcase to minimize the amount that the bottle will move and vibrate during transport.
>
> **PURCHASE WINE GEAR**
>   If wrapping your expensive bottle of wine in clothing feels too risky, you can spend on gadgets to aid your traveling woes. Reusable [WineSkin](http://www.wineskin.net/) transport bags are available for purchase online or through various retailers. Only $15 for a pack of three, this wine-shaped bag incorporates bubble wrap to secure your bottle during travel. While the skin does have an adhesive, you can add some extra insurance by also sealing it with duct tape. Alternatively, the [VinniBag](http://ellessco.com/) costs about $28 and inflates around each bottle of wine for added protection. And if you typically transport a large number of wine bottles on trips, it’s worth it to invest $70 in [Wine Check](http://www.thewinecheck.com/). The easy-to-transport case, which features wheels and a handy strap, can carry up to 12 bottles of wine in its Styrofoam and padded container. With the bottles included, the case still meets the checked-bag weight limit. If you’re in a last-mintue airport jam, Southwest Airlines usually has $5 wine packaging for purchase at ticket counters.
>
> **BACKUP PLAN**
>   Wineries usually offer direct shipping deals that save you the hassle (and space) of packing a bottle of wine in your luggage. Depending on where you purchase from, shipping charges are sometimes small or non-existent.